# Clarity Tree View - Programatically Routing to Nodes

Tags: vmware-clarity

I have a Tree View that is build dynamically based on a REST call. The full taxonomy is delivered initially, though we may implement lazy loading later.

Does anyone have an example of the following or at least a suggestion on where to begin for the following use cases:

1. I need to route into the tree for a specific node. If the url is .../node2/child3/child5, I need the tree to open to those 3 levels and automatically select that Child5 node item.
2. If opening the tree without routing, have the tree auto-expand the first level and select the first root node.

The Tree that I have build thus far looks like this:

```
   <clr-tree-node *ngIf="taxonomy">
                <ng-template #recursiveTree let-taxonomy>
                    <clr-tree-node *ngFor="let child of taxonomy">
                        <button (click)="openFile(child, null)" class="clr-treenode-link">
                            {{child.en_name}}
                        </button>
                        <ng-template [clrIfExpanded]="false" *ngIf="child.children?.length > 0">
                            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveTree; context:{ $implicit: child.children }"></ng-container>
                        </ng-template>
                    </clr-tree-node>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveTree; context:{ $implicit: taxonomy }"></ng-container>
            </clr-tree-node>
```

Comment: Do you know the structure of your data and have a way to build the static routes with parameters? If not, you are going to have trouble with routing here, because you can't lazy load routes (at least not without some major hackery, you can lazy load a module, but it must be defined during build time).

Comment: It is possible to build the route using parameters instead. I'm also building the calling application that will send the request... so I can construct the URL anyway as needed.

Just so I'm clear, you are suggesting: 

.../taxonomy?level1=aaa?level2=bbb?level3=ccc

That would be workable.

I am still confused on how to iterate through the tree to find the respective nodes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very specialized to your dataset, so in general the issue you need to resolve is knowing which of the `clrIfExpanded` directives should be set to true. You've got it hard coded to `false` in the example above. I'd suggest you use a property on the tree itself (like `node.expanded`) to store the expanded state, set to false by default.

Then, you'd have to inspect the route and params, load your data, parse the tree yourself and change the `node.expanded` property to `true` to expand. So to update your example:

```
<clr-tree-node *ngIf="taxonomy">
            <ng-template #recursiveTree let-taxonomy>
                <clr-tree-node *ngFor="let child of taxonomy">
                    <button (click)="openFile(child, null)" class="clr-treenode-link">
                        {{child.en_name}}
                    </button>
                    <ng-template [clrIfExpanded]="child.expanded" *ngIf="child.children?.length > 0">
                        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveTree; context:{ $implicit: child.children }"></ng-container>
                    </ng-template>
                </clr-tree-node>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveTree; context:{ $implicit: taxonomy }"></ng-container>
        </clr-tree-node>
```

Then you would have to parse the data structure after it loads from the API, compare the route params against it, and toggle the `child.expanded` properties for any parts of the route.